# SQL SELECT command with interval swap to following

Tags: mysql, oracle, plsql

I need change this query with interval:

```
select PRZ.id_przychodni ,extract(year from w.data_wizyty) as miesiac,
extract(month from w.data_wizyty) as miesiac
,sum(w.koszt_wizyty) over(Partition by PRZ.id_przychodni order by w.data_wizyty desc 
range between interval '10' month preceding and current row)as zarobek
from przychodnia prz join gabinet g on prz.id_przychodni= g.id_przychodni
join wizyta w on w.id_gabinet = g.id_gabinet;
```

result:

[enter link result]

[image: 1]

to query with following statement

```
select PRZ.id_przychodni ,extract(year from w.data_wizyty) as miesiac,
extract(month from w.data_wizyty) as miesiac
,sum(w.koszt_wizyty) over(Partition by PRZ.id_przychodni order by w.data_wizyty desc 
rows between 10 preceding and 10 following)as zarobek
from przychodnia prz join gabinet g on prz.id_przychodni= g.id_przychodni
join wizyta w on w.id_gabinet = g.id_gabinet;
```

result:

[enter link result]

[image: 2]

the data for "zarobek" column does not match, can it be done to get the same results ? but with following statement

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output and a clear explanation

Comment: @eshirvana I added the results, I wants the results in the "zarobek" column to be the same like in the first query when i used interval.

Comment: then use first query , I don't understand , if the first query produces what you want , then what's the problem! also only tag the dbms are you using, is it mysql or oracle?

Comment: Besides results you need to provide table definitions (ddl) and sample data in those tables, as text - **no images**, or better provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).